# Problems on sending POST requests with Ruby RestClient

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I want to submit a form with Ruby RestClient to get the BibTex files for some papers. This is the request caught by the browser:

```
Request URL:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/downloadCitations
Request Method:
POST

Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Request Payload
recordIds=6665065&citations-format=citation-only&download-format=download-bibtex&x=74&y=7
```

So here is my Ruby script:

```
response = RestClient.post("http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/downloadCitations", "recordIds"=> 6665065, "citations-format" => "citation-only", "download-format" => "download-bibtex", "x" => "74", "y" => "7"){|response, request, result, &block|
                    if [301, 302, 307].include?(response.code)
                            puts response
                    else
                            response.return!(request, result, &block)
                    end
            }
puts response
```

Though I could get the correct results directly in my browser, the script kept returning this:

```
<html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
<p>It's now at <a href="http://ieeexplore.ieee.org:80/xpl/downloadCitations?reload=true">http://ieeexplore.ieee.org:80/xpl/downloadCitations?reload=true</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Does anybody know why this happens?
Thanks!

Comment: It's just a 302 Moved Temporarily: `response.code` is 302, so you are in the true block of the if (`puts response`). The difference is due to the fact that your browser follows the redirect, while `RestClient` doesn't

Comment: So do you know how to follow the redirect using RestClient?

Comment: I found an answer that seems just what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355215/ruby-restclient-post-for-login-form

Comment: Thanks! It works! I tried Mechanize but since the BibTex returned does not have a content type "text/html", Mechanize is not able to initialize a new Page. Hence I could only use RestClient.